# How can I display Access report in ac.preview view when rest of Access screen has been hidden?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-reports

I have a database and when it opens code runs which hides everything in Access apart from a form.
This looks great for the user but I believe this is preventing me from displaying Reports in acViewPreview view.
If I prevent the On Load code from running then I am able to view reports in acViewPreview view.

I do not fully understand the code that hides everything on the form On Load event (I copied it years ago and it worked but I cannot recall from where so cannot credit the actual creator).

The code that hides Access:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Call fSetAccessWindow(0)
End Sub

Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Global Const SW_HIDE = 0
Global Const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1
Global Const SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2
Global Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3

Private Declare Function apiShowWindow Lib "user32" _
Alias "ShowWindow" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long

Function fSetAccessWindow(nCmdShow As Long)

Dim loX As Long
Dim loForm As Form
On Error Resume Next
Set loForm = Screen.ActiveForm

If Err <> 0 Then
    loX = apiShowWindow(hWndAccessApp, nCmdShow)
    Err.Clear
End If

If nCmdShow = SW_SHOWMINIMIZED And loForm.Modal = True Then
    MsgBox "Cannot minimize Access with " _
      & (loForm.Caption + " ") _
      & "form on screen"
ElseIf nCmdShow = SW_HIDE And loForm.PopUp <> True Then
    MsgBox "Cannot hide Access with " _
      & (loForm.Caption + " ") _
      & "form on screen"
Else
    loX = apiShowWindow(hWndAccessApp, nCmdShow)
End If
fSetAccessWindow = (loX <> 0)
End Function
```

How do I either temporarily reverse/disable the On Load code but only when a Report is run or perhaps there is an alternative way of viewing the Report that would work whilst Access is hidden by the On Load code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Comment out* the code line (the single-quote) to prevent the call of the function:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    ' Call fSetAccessWindow(0)
End Sub
```

or call it to "show the window normal":

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Call fSetAccessWindow(1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gustav that does the job. I have a further question though relating to this issue. Should I ask it as a separate new question or add it here?

Comment: Great. And yes, new question, please, for others to follow.